# How to make notifications float and right aligned in css vuejs

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am building a basic notification component but I'm having a hard time making it position top right correctly. Here is my html:

```
<div class="notifications">
  <p>{{ notification.message }}</p>
</div>
```

And here is my `notifications` class:

```
.notifications {
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

In this version, the notifications appear in the bottom left of the screen https://jsfiddle.net/fb343fh6/

Here is my other attempt:

```
  .notifications {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
```

In this version, the notifications appear correctly in the top right of the screen, but only one notification appears https://jsfiddle.net/762gg0bm/

Note - I am using vue.js as my front end framework

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: the "bottom left" demo actually is the same as "top right"

Answer (score 0):

Your notifications are overlapping as all of those have same position set in the style. With `vue.js` you can change their position dynamically. TO give an example I have added a `left` style to the `notification` div and assigned it's position randomly. You can see the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fb343fh6/1/).

**JS**:

```
  methods: {
    addNotification () {
      this.notifications.push({ message: 'Some error message...', leftPos: Math.random() * 500 })
      this.notification_count += 1
    }
  }
```

**HTML**:

```
<template id="notification">
  <div class="notifications" :style="{left: notification.leftPos + 'px'}">
    <p>{{ notification.message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```